# World Cup Cricket Live Match Streaming API

Tags: java, android, live-streaming

If I want to develop an android application for live streaming cricket match in cricket world cup, how can I get the API for live streaming match?

Comment: This is going to be closed because as stated, it's not a match for how SO does things.  But clearly, your first step would be to contact the owner of the IP: whoever owns the broadcast and streaming rights for these matches.

Answer (score 2):

Cricinfo provides api to get the information about various matches and current ongoing matches. You can evaluate the api. I provide below the link.

https://www.cricapi.com/